# Why won't my spinner run the onItemSelected that it is attached to even though it clicks?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to add a spinner to one of my activities where i can dynamically add items to the spinner from a set of fields so that when i click on an item in that spinner it repopulates those fields. Adding the items from the fields to the listener works fine, but when i try to click on the spinner to re populate the fields. It is still a work in progress so there is excess code.

This is the code for the class that is running

```
package com.SpurFlys.pocketscout;

import java.util.*;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class TeamSelection extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{

private Spinner spinner;
private static final List<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
private String tournamentName;
Tournament tournament = new Tournament(); 
EditText mEdit1;
EditText mEdit2;
EditText mEdit3;
EditText mEdit4;
EditText mEdit5;
EditText mEdit6;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_team_selection);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    tournamentName = intent.getExtras().getString("tournamentName");
    tournament.name = tournamentName;

    spinner = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<String>adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(TeamSelection.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,paths);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.team_selection, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

    String teamNumber = tournament.teamIndex.get(position);
    mEdit1.setText(teamNumber);
    String[] temp = tournament.teams.get(teamNumber);
    String auton = temp[0];
    mEdit2.setText(auton);
    String chassis = temp[1];
    mEdit3.setText(chassis);
    String arm = temp[2];
    mEdit4.setText(arm);
    String intake = temp[3];
    mEdit5.setText(intake);
    String other = temp[4];
    mEdit6.setText(other);
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void addTeam(View view){
    mEdit1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    mEdit2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    mEdit3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    mEdit4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    mEdit5 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText5);
    mEdit6 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText6);
    String teamNumber = mEdit1.getText().toString();
    String auton = mEdit2.getText().toString();
    String chassis = mEdit3.getText().toString();
    String arm = mEdit4.getText().toString();
    String intake = mEdit5.getText().toString();
    String other = mEdit6.getText().toString();
    if(teamNumber.trim().equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Blank is not a valid team number", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else{
        paths.add(teamNumber);
        tournament.createTeam(teamNumber, auton, chassis, arm, intake, other, paths.indexOf(teamNumber));
        mEdit1.setText("");
        mEdit2.setText("");
        mEdit3.setText("");
        mEdit4.setText("");
        mEdit5.setText("");
        mEdit6.setText("");
    }
}
}
```

This is the code for the activity

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:contentDescription="@string/teams"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.SpurFlys.pocketscout.TeamSelection" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="11dp"
    android:onClick="addTeam"
    android:text="@string/add_team" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/team_number" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/teams" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/auton"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText2"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/chassis"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/arm"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/intake"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText6"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/other"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is the code for the tournament object that is called

```
package com.SpurFlys.pocketscout;

import java.util.*;

public class Tournament {

public String name;
public String date;
public String address;
public String city;
public String state;
public String country;
public String postalCode;
public Map<String, String[]> teams;
public Map<String, String> teamIndex = new HashMap<String, String>();
String[] tempTeam;

public Tournament() {
    teams = new HashMap<String, String[]>();
    tempTeam = new String[5];

}

public void createTeam(String number, String auton, String chassis, String arm, String intake, String other, int index){
    teamIndex.put(Integer.valueOf(index).toString(), number);
    tempTeam[0] = auton;
    tempTeam[1] = chassis;
    tempTeam[2] = arm;
    tempTeam[3] = intake;
    tempTeam[4] = other;

    teams.put(number, tempTeam);

}

}
```

Comment: Print a log message in onItemSelected, and then see it in logcat.

Comment: It Never never even gets to the onItemSelected in the debug screen so there is nothing to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                //you should be switching on the view, since the class is implementing onItemSelectedListenter
        switch(v.getId()){
            case (R.id.spinner):
                //logic for setting mEdit1.setText(teamNumber), etc..
            break;
        }
}
```

Since you implemented the onItemSelectedListener for the activity, you must set the cases for which form object should do what when selected. Say you had another spinner. That spinner would also take `this` as the arg for setting the `onItemSelectedListener`. The application has no way of knowing what it should do in each instance unless it knows which `view` was selected.

Comment: The problem is that it never even gets to the onItemSelected. When I insert a breakpoint on that line it doesn't get there.

Comment: it gives me the message Attempted to finish an input event but the input event receiver has already been disposed.

Comment: are you selecting the same item? in that case, the above method would not be called as you have not implemented the `onNothingSelected` method

Comment: It gives me the same error on the initial press of an item on the spinner.